# Plugin certification being blocked due to Safari pop-up blocker

Tags: safari, outlook-web-addins, office-store, popup-blocker

We have submitted our outlook plugin for certification and received the following message back:

"The add-in did not pass compatibility tests for Outlook on the Web in Safari (Version:13.1(15609.1.20.111.8)).

Nothing appears to be launched when we click "Schedule" button in message read mode in the above browser."

We can reproduce this locally, but the cause is that the pop-up blocker is blocking the window that office sdk is attempting to open when we call `Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentForm`. Our plugin does not specifically call window.open.

We have also tested this behavior in Firefox and we get the same results. Please let me know how to go forward from here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Questions asking about the store's terms & conditions or seeking customer service are off-topic."

Comment: I've scoured the internet to try to find a place where I can email or speak with someone. I have not found anything but this as a choice. I need to speak with anyone with the partner center

Comment: We need more clarity in order to repro this issue. Can you please provide us the following information?

How are you calling the "displayNewAppointmentForm" API?

What does the schedule mean here? It is the native outlook feature or your implementation.

To understand more about it, please help us reproduce the issue (with code snippets/manifest/screenshots ) 

I see the issue is also reproducible for Firefox (from the post). Does it only happen for mac?